# Drupal Remove Global Block from singe page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks

I have a Drupal site that has a block on the bottom of every page. There is one page I do not want this block. How do I remove it from that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the block configuration page, go to the very bottom. `Visibility settings` section.

Open the `Pages` tab. Check `All pages except those listed` and type the pages you don not want to show the blocks into inside the textarea.

Hope this help.

Comment: What is the URL? Use the node url i.e. node/7